# Use Group By without Aggregate

Tags: postgresql, group-by, aggregate

I have below data

```
UserId      Val   txt
100         10     A
200         25     B
100         30     GV
300         15     BHG
200         20     BGV
```

and want to write a query that give min(val) for each user

Result :

```
100        10      A
200        20      BGV
300        15      BHG
```

Comment: What is the logic to select from the `val` field. For `UserId` `200` you have `20` as the `val`. Why `20`? Why is `userid` `100` getting `txt` value `A` and not `txt` value `GV` or `AGV`. This all comes off as very arbitrary.

Comment: select min(val) for each user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (userID) *
FROM your_table
ORDER BY userID, val
```

Comment: @user3780058 Have you tried the query? It will give you the result you described. It will give you records with minimal value.